# monitoring file update using c++

Tags: python, c++, winapi, mfc

In c++ using windows api how do i monitor file change event

like: "this_program.py" is updating a text file.

```
outfile.open("some_file_1.txt",ios::out);
```

- then edit "some_file_1.txt",
- "some_file_1.txt" triggers some window event,
- I want to monitor and log who is updating "some_file_1.txt",
- like I am updating from "this_program.py", etc....

so I can monitor file changes on filesystem, using winapi or mfc in c++ or 
python.

what event to monitor, like how to set the hook to get the source file.

```
outfile.close();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no specific MFC option for this (as far as I know). You can use `FindFirstChangeNotification` to monitor the entire folder for changes. If change is detected then your file is possibly changed (or maybe it was another file that was changed). Read the date/time stamp on your file to see if change occured. Another function is `ReadDirectoryChanges` which has more options. It doesn't tell you who changed the file.

```
HWND hMainWnd;
FILETIME SaveFileTime;

DWORD WINAPI checkfolder(void* arg)
{
    wchar_t folder[MAX_PATH];
    lstrcpy(folder, (const wchar_t*)arg);

    for (;;)
    {
        HANDLE hfolder = FindFirstChangeNotification(folder, FALSE,
                FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_LAST_WRITE | FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_FILE_NAME);
        WaitForSingleObject(hfolder, INFINITE);
        if (!::IsWindow(hMainWnd)) break;
        PostMessage(hMainWnd, WM_COMMAND, ID_MY_MESSAGE, 0);
        FindCloseChangeNotification(hfolder);
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(...)
{
    //save last write time
    WIN32_FIND_DATA data;
    HANDLE h = FindFirstFile(L"c:\\test\\file.txt", &data);
    if (h != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) SaveFileTime = data.ftLastWriteTime;
    FindClose(h);

    //watch for changes
    CreateThread(NULL, 0, checkfolder, L"c:\\test", 0, NULL);
}

void OnMyMessage()
{
    WIN32_FIND_DATA data;
    HANDLE handle = FindFirstFile(L"c:\\test\\file.txt", &data);
    if (handle != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        FindClose(handle);
        if (CompareFileTime(&data.ftLastWriteTime, &SaveFileTime) != 0)
            OutputDebugStringA("file.txt was modified\n");
        else
            OutputDebugStringA("Another file in the same directory was modified\n");
    }
    else
    {
        OutputDebugStringA("file.txt was deleted, or directory was removed/renamed\n");
    }
}
```